# C# WPF - Dynamically Change Text Color based on Background Image

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts, colors

I'm working on a program using C# and WPF and I was curious about getting the text color of some text I have to change dynamically based on what the background image I set is.

The background images are loaded by random (I will have no control over what they are) and I need to maintain readability of the fonts depending on what it is.

As you can see here: http://i.gyazo.com/820c45dde9d767dcd7ab2a92bd1de898.png

With this background image set, there's no way to read what the text has to say. Meanwhile, it would look fine on a lighter background.

Basically what I think needs to happen is

1. Get the most used color in that image
2. Find out if it's a "light or dark color"
3. Change the text accordingly
   How could I do this? Whether it's programmatically or in the WPF XAML (i'm still new to using WPF so bear with me there).

Thanks in advanced,

Mike

Comment: you can use converters to 'set properties after processing some data'. take a look at http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html. If you can bind to the image and use converter, you can set the foreground of the Text element.

Comment: There's still a good chance your text wont be readable. If the most used color is black and you decide to use white, there's still a chance that the text will sit over some white area of the background. Black text with a white outline can be read over anything though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that trying to select a text colour dynamically isn't ideal. Even if you select a colour that makes some of the text visible there is no guarantee it won't pass through a portion of your images which hides it.

Personally I would use a label with a white background but reduce the background opacity to show some part of the image behind. That way your text will always sit on a lightened area and dark text will always work.

Andy.